# Creating Child object inside parent class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I have a scenario of routing http calls based on device information.

For that my design is :

A single and common controller where all devices will request to,and on identification of device we need to route it to device specific controller , in this process i had to create object of child inside parent and access function of child.

I wonder if this is correct?

I think libraries should remain intact and all device based logic should be at controller and view level only.

Note  creating child object inside parent don't give error in PHP

Comment: In general a parent should not know about any children. There's a direct 1:1 relationship between a child and its parent, but there's an infinite 1:n relationship between a parent and possible classes that extend it, which the parent cannot reasonably know about. Why does the child-controller factory need to be in the same class hierarchy to begin with? Can't Controller A construct a different Controller B without them being related? (Hint: yes, it can)

Comment: Parent child relationship need to maintained as some properties are common and i want to reuse using inheritance.